# JDBC getConnection timeout issue

Tags: java, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I have an application that uses connection pooling to get database connection from an Oracle9i release 9.2.0.4 database. Application is hosted in SJSAS 8.1 and the driver is `ojdbc14.jar` version 10.1.0.4.

The problem I'm having is `datasource.getConnection()` method is taking about 40 secs to throw an exception when the DB is down! This is causing the application to get overloaded during a DB outage. I tried setting `LoginTimeout=8` with the datasource but it has no effect.

Please see below the datasource I'm using

```
<jdbc-connection-pool connection-validation-method="table" 
                      datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
                      fail-all-connections="true" 
                      idle-time out-in-seconds="600" 
                      is-connection-validation-required="true" 
                      is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" 
                      max-pool-size="100" 
                      max-wait-time-in-millis="8000" 
                      name="mydb" 
                      pool-resize-quantity="80" 
                      res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                      steady-pool-size="20" 
                      validation-table-name="dual">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1:1521:mydb"/>
    <property name="user" value="user1"/>
    <property name="LoginTimeout" value="8"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass1"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Can any one please help? I need the `getConnection()` method to timeout with in the timeout given.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few things to try:

From "Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference".

Using JDBC with Firewalls

Firewall timeout for idle-connections may sever a connection. This can cause JDBC applications to hang while waiting for a connection. You can perform one or more of the following actions to avoid connections from being severed due to firewall timeout:

- If you are using connection caching
  or connection pooling, then always
  set the inactivity timeout value on
  the connection cache to be shorter
  than the firewall idle timeout value.
- Pass `oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT` as
  connection property to enable read
  timeout on socket. The timeout value
  is in milliseconds.
- For both JDBC OCI and JDBC Thin
  drivers, use net descriptor to
  connect to the database and specify
  the ENABLE=BROKEN parameter in the
  DESCRIPTION clause in the connect
  descriptor. Also, set a lower value
  for `tcp_keepalive_interval`.
- Enable Oracle Net DCD by setting
  `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=1` in the
  `sqlnet.ora` file on the server-side.

Comment: The question is about 'when the DB is down'. That makes your entire answer irrelevant.

Comment: It is relevant.  The first 3 bullet points are all things you do on the client side not the DB side.  It's about getting the client side to timeout quicker.